# How add const to await page.$x in puppeteer Node.js? Const in xpath

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, puppeteer, href, contains

I want to add cont to href link. I want to use const. I had problem with:

```
const klik2 = await page.$x("//a[contains(@href, 'p2')]");
```

I want to add

```
const new = 'p' + [i];
```

Where now is 'p2'. How do it correctly ?

My actual code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
await page.goto("http://mypage.test/");
for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
const link = 'p' + [i];
try {

const klik2 = await page.$x("//a[contains(@href, link)]");
await klik2[0].click();
```

}
catch {

```
   console.log(e);
```

}

```
   await page.goto("http://mypage.test/");


})();
```

Also had trying something like this:

```
const klik3 = "'" + 'p1' + "'";
const klik = '"//a[contains(@href,' + klik3 + ')]"';
console.log(klik);
const klik2 = await page.$x(klik);
await klik2[0].click();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What's `i`? Usually it makes no sense to concat a string and an array.

Comment: I want use    " for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {    const link = [i]; " , there are links with p1,p2,p3 etc

Comment: Can you edit the post to include that code and show the page you're working with. What data are you trying to get? Do you mean ```for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) { const link = `p${i}`; }``` or `"p" + i`? Again, I'm not sure why you'd put `i` in a single element array.

Comment: Every link contains p + number,  first element contains p1, second contains p2, third p3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template literals (template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Also, it seems you do not need an array in your concatenation (here: `const link = 'p' + [i];`)

```js
const link = 'p' + i;
try {
  const klik2 = await page.$x(`//a[contains(@href, '${link}')]`);
  await klik2[0].click();
}
```

Comment: just if anyone is wondering, it is case sensitive